# Допоможіть перекласти слово "Оскорбление"!

Tags: переклад

Це не "образа" і не "кривда". А що?

Comment: Поясність, будь ласка, який саме відтінок значення Ви хочете передати. Бо між словами двох різних мов немає відповідності 1-до-1: може статися, що в різних контекстах одне й те саме слово доведеться передавати по-різному. І тут, мені здається, саме та ситуація.

Comment: Ось обговорення цієї теми у фейсбук-групі «Український переклад»: [2017-01-26 від Андрія Нікітіна](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1253916181310814/) та [2017-03-21 від Руслани Ярусяк](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1303732622995836/).

Comment: Хоча питання дуже цікаве (навіть без контексту). Але без контексту воно (по-моєму) надто широке. Наведіть, будь ласка, приклади речень, у яких слово «оскорбление» у потрібному Вам значенні.

Comment: Багатьма словами, мабуть, можна сказати «спроба зачепити (чиюсь) гідність».

Comment: Чому не _образа_ чи _кривда_? Розкажіть власними словами, шчо для вас є _оскорбление_ і наведіть приклади.

Comment: Переклад [Оскорбле́ние](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) на r2u.org.ua

Answer (score 2):

Словник [Єфремова-Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on) надає кілька варіантів перекладу:

> **Оскорбле́ние** – обра́за, ура́за, нару́га, кри́вда, знева́га.

Гадаю, що саме *"наруга"* (чи, скажімо, *"поруга"*) дуже добре відповідає значенню оригінального слова в російській.

Словник [Ніковського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=8&highlight=on) подає ще такий варіант:

> **Оско́рб, -бу** – оскорбление, обида, несправедливость.

Можливо для вашого контексту придасться, хоча я сам бачу це слово вперше.

Comment: Оскорбле́ние - це ситуація, коли уражене почуття власної гідності. Не образа - ображеного можна пожаліти. Не кривда - вона припускає матеріальний збиток. Саме оскорбление як приниження, але у власній самооцінці. Мабуть, все ж таки "зневага"?! Дякую, спробую звикнути.

Comment: @Ninon а хіба *оскорбленного* не можна пожаліти? Був би вдячний якби ви відредагували запитання і пояснили чим саме на вашу думку відрізняється *образа* від *оскорление*.

Answer (score 2):

Якщо вас не задовольняють словники - ось декілька прикладів з юридичного вжитку:

Кримінальний кодекс України зразка 1960 року (втратив чинність з 1 вересня 2001 року) має [статтю 126](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/KD0006.html) у редакції 1995 року:

> **Стаття 126. *Образа***
> *Образа*, тобто умисне приниження честі і гідності особи, виражене в непристойній формі, -
> карається виправними роботами на строк до одного року, або штрафом від тридцяти до вісімдесяти мінімальних розмірів заробітної плати або громадською доганою.

Чинний кримінальний кодекс не має такої статті, але у 2012 році [вносився проект змін](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/JF8HX00A.html) до кодексу, який додавав подібну статтю 145<sup>2</sup> (проте був відхилений):

> **Стаття 145<sup>2</sup>. *Образа***
>
> 1. **Образа**, тобто приниження честі та гідності іншої особи, виражене в непристойній формі, - карається штрафом в розмірі до 500 неоподаткованих мінімумів доходів громадян або виправними роботами на строк до шести місяців;
> 2. **Образа**, що міститься в публічному виступі, публічно демонструються у творах або засобах масової інформації, - карається штрафом в розмірі від 500 до 1000 неоподаткованих мінімумів доходів громадян або виправними роботами на строк до одного року;